# jQuery Mobile 'Form' is not getting submitted from the iPhone soft keyboard "GO" button in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am writing simple form with two text boxes for logIn process and wanted to get this form

submitted on the click of "Go" button of the i-Phone keyboard which get open as the textbox

gets focus.

When i keep a submit button with these two text boxes the go button starts working otherwise

it won't.

i am using

jQuery mobile v1.2.0

PhoneGap v2.5

**code without submit button:**

```
<form id="loginForm">

   <div class="ui-body">

      <div data-role="controlgroup" id="my-controlgroup">

          <input data-theme="b" type="text" name="text-username" id="text-username" placeholder="Username" value="" />

          <input data-theme="b" type="password" name="text-pwd" id="text-pwd"  placeholder="Password" value="" />

      </div>
   </div>

</form>
```

**code with submit button:**

```
<form id="loginForm" data-ajax="false">

   <div class="ui-body">

     <div data-role="controlgroup" id="my-controlgroup">

       <input data-theme="b" type="text" name="text-username" id="text-username"  placeholder="Username" value="" />

       <input data-theme="b" type="password" name="text-pwd" id="text-pwd"  placeholder="Password" value="" />

       <button type="submit" data-theme="none" name="submit" value=""></button>

     </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

I don't need submit but since i have to submit form using iPhone soft keyboard any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

you need a `keypress` event my friend. The "Go" button on your phone is equivalent to the Enter key of your physical keyboard. You have to check for that `keyCode`. Here's a code :

```
$("#my-controlgroup").on("keypress", "input[type=text]", function(e) {
    //check for enter key 
    if(e.which === 13) {
        //check for empty input
        if($("input:empty").length === 0) {
           alert("submitted!");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Suhx/), if it helps !

```
<form id="loginForm" data-ajax="false">

   <div class="ui-body">

     <div data-role="controlgroup" id="my-controlgroup">

       <input data-theme="b" type="text" name="text-username" id="text-username"  placeholder="Username" value="" />

       <input data-theme="b" type="password" name="text-pwd" id="text-pwd"  placeholder="Password" value="" />

       <button type="submit" data-theme="none" name="submit" value="">GO</button>

     </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but you have misunderstood the question! I don't need any button in the form since i am using jquery mobile in phonegap so when textbox gets the focus a soft keybord of the mobile opens and there it have a "Go" button.which on tap will submit the Form.